# Getting check out time of revision from SVN

Tags: svn

I am using SVN and want to know the time of checking out of the particular revision from SVN. Is there any command in SVN that can help me in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tortuise simply press show log button in checkout form and choose the commit you want to extract from your repository

[image]

By command line just add -r and the revision number that you want to checkout.

I mean:

- type "svn log" command to view all commits and their time.
- type "svn -r [your rev number] [repository]